# Loop Through NSArray And Check Objects in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, loops, object, nsarray

I'm trying to loop inside the objects of my array and would like to know how can I check the contents of the objects inside it and then do something when my search doesn't apply.

For example:

```
myArray = @[@"A1", @"A2", @"A3", @"B1", @"B2", @"B3", @"C1", @"C2", @"C3"];
```

I'd like to check the contents of myArray and if the object contains the letter A, I'll actually create a button until I create a row of buttons with objects of the letter A. If it contains a different letter, say B, I'll create a different row of buttons below the letter A row of buttons.

It will look like this:

```
[A1] [A2] [A3]
[B1] [B2] [B3]
[C1] [C2] [C3]
```

I'm thinking of doing a fast enumeration like this:

```
for (NSString *string in myArray) 
{
    if (// string has letter A)
    {
        Add string to array of A
    }
    else if (// string has letter B)
    {
        Add string to array of B
    }
    else if (// string has letter C)
    {
        Add string to array of C
    }
}
```

But I'm not sure if I'm doing it right and fast.

Comment: Assuming the `if` statement conditions are correct, what you posted looks right. What is your question?

Comment: How to log or map the buttons the way I wanted it as illustrated above? The buttons will be placed inside a `UIScrollView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of approach might help indirectly. I'm not entirely sure what is being asked, so make of this what you will.

If you want to gather up by prefix, build an `NSMutableDictionary` whose keys will be `@"A", @"B", ...` and values are instances of `NSMutableArray`. For each string in your `myArray`, take it's prefix as the key to look up the array value in the dictionary, and add.

Something along the following lines:

```
NSArray *myArray = @[@"A1", @"A2", @"A3", @"B1", @"B2", @"B3", @"C1", @"C2", @"C3"];
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (NSString *s in myArray) {
    if ([s length] < 1) {
        continue;
    }
    NSString *key = [s substringToIndex:1];
    if (![dict objectForKey:key]) {
        [dict setObject:[NSMutableArray array] forKey:key];
    }
    NSMutableArray *bucket = [dict objectForKey:key];
    [bucket addObject:s];
}
```

This kind of approach, which again may not directly answer your question, might prove instructive. It also has the advantage of being extensible - no need for yet another `if` clause.

Edit: The output of 'po dict' above in the console reads

```
(lldb) po dict
$2 = 0x0a33e660 {
    A =     (
        A1,
        A2,
        A3
    );
    B =     (
        B1,
        B2,
        B3
    );
    C =     (
        C1,
        C2,
        C3
    );
}
```

Comment: I basically want to map all cinema seats. I have an array of available seats and an array of all seats. I already managed to merge both arrays with seats that are available and taken and I just want to map the seats in my scrollview.

Comment: I'll try this. I basically wanted to eliminate the use of multiple ifs since the letters may range up to letter Z.

Comment: How can I get the main dictionary with all the keys and its array objects? The bucket keeps on getting empty when it fills all the values of a certain letter.

Comment: I tested my code sample and it's WFM. See the edit showing a printout in my console. I can't reproduce the "getting empty".

Comment: I tried it on mine and I log the result of bucket after you add an object in it. I can't log it outside of the for loop since bucket is declared inside the for loop.

Comment: I think you might be looking at different buckets. Bucket A starts out empty, as do all buckets. When bucket A fills, the bucket pointer points at bucket B - which to start with is empty - and starts filling. What you seem to be reporting appears to be intended behaviour, I'm really not sure what the problem is. You could try printing dict out in the console, or set a breakpoint outside of the for-loop and inspect it then.

Comment: Nevermind. I should be logging dict instead of bucket after the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Find the character in string by using NSRange and do ur stuff. Like this 
Try :

```
 for (NSString *string in myArray) 
    {
        if ([string rangeOfString:@"A"].location != NSNotFound)//Contains "A"
        {
            Add string to array of A
        }
        else if ([string rangeOfString:@"B"].location != NSNotFound)//Contains "B"
        {
            Add string to array of B
        }
        else if ([string rangeOfString:@"C"].location != NSNotFound)//Contains "C"
        {
            Add string to array of C
        }
    }
```

ope this helps u.